# while True: not working with turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

When I import turtle, then try to use a `while True:` loop with it it doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
import turtle
import time

stage = turtle.Turtle()

width = 900
height = 500

def up():
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.forward(10)

def down():
    turtle.setheading(270)
    turtle.forward(10)

def char():
    turtle.listen()
    turtle.onkey(up, 'w')
    turtle.onkey(up, 's')

turtle.setup(width, height)
turtle.goto(390, 0)
char()

while True:
    if (turtle.ycor() >= 250):
        turtle.goto(460, 0) 

stage.goto(350, 0)
turtle.done()
```

I have no idea why it isn't working, it just freezes (not responding) then, no error messages. It's really annoying, as the same thing has happened with other programs where I had turtle and while true loops.

If while True is the issue, is there any other way to 'forever check if', thanks!

Comment: Where do you finish your `while` loop?

Comment: Why do you expect `turtle.ycor() >= 250` when `turtle` is at `(390,0)` i.e. when it's y-coordinate is equal to zero?

Comment: Because you move the turtle up and down, but I can't because the window becomes not responding, You move it with W and S, when it hits the top, it goes back down

Comment: how do you finish a while loop?

Comment: If you start `while True`, then you either need to `break` or (if you're in a function) `return`.

Comment: Thank you, its solved :D But! If I break it, then it it won't check if it is above the set coordinate forever. Solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than your infinite loop, you can have any routine that moves the turtle check if the turtle has reached the boundary of interest:

```
import turtle

WIDTH = 900
HEIGHT = 500

def up():
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.forward(10)
    check()

def down():
    turtle.setheading(270)
    turtle.forward(10)
    check()

def check():
    if turtle.ycor() >= HEIGHT/2:
        turtle.goto(400, 0) 

turtle.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

turtle.goto(350, 0)

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(up, 'w')
turtle.onkey(down, 's')

turtle.done()
```

Also note that your original code had two turtles, the default one and one called `stage` -- make sure to keep track of the turtle you're manipulating!  Also, get on top of your coordinate system, you were moving the turtle off screen (unless that's what you wanted) with no way to move it back on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know exactly what you need to accomplish, but you could probably just put the

```
if (turtle.ycor() >= 250):
    turtle.goto(460, 0)
```

inside up() and down().

Although if you need to have the function run forever, as you mentioned in your comment, you can put your `while True:` thing inside a second thread, which should keep your window from freezing.